# app in not getting installed in wso2 appmanager

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-appm, wso2-iot

I am trying to install the mobile app on my device through the wso2 appmanager, but on clicking its reflecting as installed but the app is not getting installed on my device.Any help will be really  appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Means the wso2 appmanager when i am accessing that url (i am running on my local host) on my device it is also running but the app is not getting installed...

Comment: Can you go in to the EMM console and access the device view where you can see the device details and apply operations. In this can you see the application install operation in pending state? In the documentation, Im referring to the 4th step where in the left hand side bar you have an operations log.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM210/Applying+Operations+on+Your+Device

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using andy MDM then you need to configure appmanager to download the apk file to your device and the manually install the app in your device.Follow this post[1]

1.https://jenananthan.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/how-to-use-mobile-store-in-wso2-appmanager-without-mdm/